# Error on over() Clause for am calculate the rows based on id's to next or previous value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter-2

I am facing an issue where my query is not executing and I am getting the error near the over clause but I want result like see the pic below:
[image]

I mean I want result like  25000-9000 =16000 ;
                         16000-5000 =11000;
display output like that guys and here is my query

```
query:
SELECT s.id, s.cust_id, 
s.package_name,s.pending_amount,s.pack_received_amount, s.return_amount, 
s.payment_type,s.total_package_amount, SUM('s.pending_amount') OVER (ORDER 
BY s.id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW AS s.balance FROM 
payment s WHERE s.cust_id = S1307 and s.package_name= switzerland
```

My error was here screen shot of images guys:

Comment: This version of MySQL?

Comment: yeah sql server also the same query  right what was issue

Comment: Window functions have appeared in MySQL only after version 8.0.2 and above. You are using an old version of MySQL.

Comment: hoo kk what i can i do now @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: hi @MadhurBhaiya my version of MYSQL is 10.1.37-MariaDB but still its not working

Comment: @IswaryaSwaminadhan Window functions in Mariadb are available only in 10.3+ versions. You should upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: kk @MadhurBhaiya thank u let me  try

Comment: @IswaryaSwaminadhan you can check my approach. If you think it is helpful for you.

Comment: hi @MadhurBhaiya my problem is sloved as according to your solution but when i upgrade to new mysql version am getting error before am not upgrade it okay "Field 'check_out' doesn't have a default value " it automatically place empty box in case it doesn't have .

Comment: @IswaryaSwaminadhan what is the datatype of `check_out` field ? Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and add the result of that to the question.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yeah i sloved the things using command '" SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '  ';   " it doesn't shows now error anyways thank u so much buddy for ur help have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select . . .,
       sum(s.pending_amount) over (order by s.id) as balance 
from payment s 
where s.cust_id = S1307 and s.package_name = 'switzerland';
```

If you don't have too many rows, a simple subquery will suffice:

```
select . . .,
       (select sum(s2.pending_amount)
        from payment s2
        where s2.id <= s.id and
              s2.cust_id = s.cust_id and
              s2.package_name = s.package_name
       ) as balance 
from payment s 
where s.cust_id = 'S1307' and
      s.package_name = 'switzerland';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Total,
Received,
CASE WHEN @balance = 0 THEN
(@balance := Total - Received) 
ELSE 
@balance := @balance - Received
END AS Balance
FROM
Table1,
(select @balance:=0) as t2
```

**Table1**

```
Total   Received
-----------------
25000   9000
25000   5000
```

**Output**

```
Total   Received    Balance
----------------------------
25000   9000        16000
25000   5000        11000
```

> DEMO
>
> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43cc31/18

Comment: hi @Jay Shankar Gupta i want result like when i change one column remaining column balance automatically update the values but am not understand your query and thank u for answering and am almost try ur query also

Comment: you can go for trigger, you can create a trigger on that table

Comment: these also a one method to solve the query thank u for answering